# What could cause a undefinedpageWebRequestEvents.js appearing in my logs?

Tags: javascript, safari, chromium

We're seeing this extremely rare, extremely odd bug in our logs.  When some people (I believe most are on Safari) are trying to access various pages on our site, they get an error and can't proceed.  When I check the logs, I see URLs with `undefinedpageWebRequestEvents.js` in them.

I've searched around but can't seem to find any explanation of what this might be or what might be causing them.  There is VERY little javascript on this site, and hundreds of thousands of others are not seeing this error (including us - we cannot duplicate) so any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Suppose `var linkStartsWith = ...`, and later some load function with `link =
 linkStartsWith + 'pageWebRequestEvents.js;'`... In this hypotetical situation if `linkStartsWith` is undefined, you will see your error. Are you concatenating links somewhere?

Comment: No where.  We're using jQuery 1.11.1 and all the links are standard HTML requests - nothing js based.  It's a rails app but we're not using turbo links or anything.

Comment: I have the same issue, still investigating, maybe a tracker library causes this

Comment: @JoshL This maybe a plugin that user uses for his browser, any chance to get more clue?

Comment: @HieuPham I would to but the people using the site arent sophisticated enough to report that and I cant find a site that would report on what browser plugins someone has that they can use to mail me a report.

Comment: @JoshL I'm seeing the same error in my logs too. Let me know if you're interested in comparing notes. I think it's coming from a 3rd party tracker (OpenTag and Snowplow are two we're using).

Comment: We had the same issue which caused small ddos because of all the 404. Are you using tinymce on those pages? I debug some of our code and I believe that tinymce, last pass extension and safari suddenly became enemies ;o)

Answer (score 7):

The Firefox LastPass extension has this string as part of `onloadwff.js`:

```
t.src=bg.get("extensionBaseURL")+"pageWebRequestEvents.js"
```

If the `bg.get("extensionBaseURL")` statement returns `undefined`, your mystery URL would be injected into a `script` tag on the page. Firefox does not appear to list local files loaded by an extension in the *Network* tab, but you should be able to track down the references the same way I did:

1. Install the extension. (LastPass Firefox Toolbar 4.1.53)
2. Load the Dev Tools' *Debugger* pane and visit a webpage.
3. Under *Sources*, you should be able to see a `data/pageWebRequestEvents.js` file under `support@lastpass.com`.
4. I searched for references to it with <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> and typing `!pageweb` into the search box (`!` for *In All Files*).
5. The references that appear are on lines that are too long to click on, but they're clearly in the `data/onloadwff.js` file.
6. Either copy that file and search through it in your favorite text editor, or load it in the *Debugger* tab and use the local file search (`#pageweb` third result).

This may also happen with Safari, but I don't know how to crack open a Safari extension's resources.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this could be related to an [infected lastpass_x64.exe](https://www.hybrid-analysis.com/sample/b2d4689ab6070ffedbb3517fcbb99a98ba5abcbb3f3bf3fc52c3d1eb060c4000?environmentId=100#sample-extracted-strings) - the strings extracted from that file include reference to a "pageWebRequestEvents.js". I am in no way affiliated with hybrid-analysis.com, so I can't tell whether their analysis is legit or sane.

For what it's worth I've seen two instances of this file being requested in the last 24 hours.

Comment: We're seeing this in our logs too. I've written to LastPass to ask if this might be a bug on their end.

Comment: @Taytay Does your inquiry have a public link?

Comment: It doesn't Michael. They told me that it's been forwarded to their engineering team.

Comment: @Taytay are you using tinymce? I'm positive, that it happens after I init tinymce in our app. Probably when textarea is hidden and new container is created. It's not the case when I use "inline" tinymce. Only regular textarea -> wysiwyg swap.

Comment: Can't edit comment anymore, so just FYI I've posted this on lastpass support forum (https://forums.lastpass.com/viewforum.php?f=14), but I'm waiting for approval